# Why the first person player is looking at the ground instead forward when the game start?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the second image the character is not the player.  the player is looking at npc character.  the player is first person. just to make clear.

When running now the game the player is looking at the ground:

[image: player is looking at the ground when the game is starting]

If i disable the script that is attached to the main camera, then the player will look forward as it should be:

[image: the script on the main camera is disable and the player is looking forward as it should be]

The player is built from a capsule and at the top of the capsule the main camera.  and the main camera is child of the capsule.

The script is attached to the main camera:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class camMouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector2 mouseLook;
    Vector2 smoothV;

    public float sensitivity = 5.0f;
    public float smoothing = 2.0f;
    public bool mouseDown = false;
    public bool cursorLock = false;
    public HandleMouseCursor handleMouseCursor;

    GameObject character;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        if (cursorLock == false)
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        }
        else
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        }
        character = this.transform.parent.gameObject;
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && mouseDown == true)
        {
            MouseLook();
        }
        else
        {
            if (mouseDown == false)
            {
                MouseLook();
            }
        }
    }

    private void MouseLook()
    {
        if (cursorLock == false)
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        }
        else
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        }

        var md = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y"));

        md = Vector2.Scale(md, new Vector2(sensitivity * smoothing, sensitivity * smoothing));
        smoothV.x = Mathf.Lerp(smoothV.x, md.x, 1f / smoothing);
        smoothV.y = Mathf.Lerp(smoothV.y, md.y, 1f / smoothing);
        mouseLook += smoothV;

        mouseLook.y = Mathf.Clamp(mouseLook.y, -90f, 90f);

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-mouseLook.y, Vector3.right);
        character.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(mouseLook.x, character.transform.up);
    }
}
```

What I have tried so far is to add a flag , but it didn't change much.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class camMouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector2 mouseLook;
    Vector2 smoothV;

    public float sensitivity = 5.0f;
    public float smoothing = 2.0f;

    GameObject character;
    private bool initialRotationSet = false;

    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;  // Always start with the cursor locked

        character = this.transform.parent.gameObject;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (!initialRotationSet)
        {
            SetInitialCameraRotation();
            initialRotationSet = true;
        }

        MouseLook();
    }

    private void SetInitialCameraRotation()
    {
        // Set the initial camera rotation to look forward
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.zero);
    }

    private void MouseLook()
    {
        var md = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y"));

        md = Vector2.Scale(md, new Vector2(sensitivity * smoothing, sensitivity * smoothing));
        smoothV.x = Mathf.Lerp(smoothV.x, md.x, 1f / smoothing);
        smoothV.y = Mathf.Lerp(smoothV.y, md.y, 1f / smoothing);
        mouseLook += smoothV;

        mouseLook.y = Mathf.Clamp(mouseLook.y, -90f, 90f);

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-mouseLook.y, Vector3.right);
        character.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(mouseLook.x, character.transform.up);
    }
}
```

Comment: id guess because looking is at 90 degrees, not up/down

Comment: @BugFinder true.  changing the clamp from -90 to 0 fixed it.  thanks.